# Count the numbers of subfolders and .exe files inside those subfolders

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Sorry for the long post, trying to be as detailed as I can.

My folder structure looks like this:

`C:\1\2\3\4\5\6\file.exe`

What I am trying to accomplish is to count the number of folders that exist in folder `6`, then group them by the time they were created. I am also trying to count the number of instances that `file.exe` exists in those folders.

So for example, folder `C:\1\2\3\4\5` contains the following sub-folders which were created at the time shown below::

```
a 12:00 AM
b 12:00 AM
c 1:00 AM
d 1:00 AM
e 2:00 AM
...
```

Of those folders, `a` and `b` contain `file.exe`.

What my expected output then should be is:

```
Time     Count Hit
----     ----- ---
12:00 AM     2   2
1:00 AM      2   0
2:00 AM      1   0
```

`Time` represents the time of the folders, `Count` is the number of folders created at that time and `Hit` is the number of instances of `file.exe` in the `C:\1\2\3\4\5\6\` path of the folders created at that time.

So for another example, at `12:00 AM`, there were `2`folders created and inside of those two folders there are subfolders containing `2` instances of `file.exe`. Make sense?

I am having a problem with counting the instances of `file.exe`.
When I run my script, it does group the folders, and gives me the time created and the number at that time but it does not give me the count of the instances of `file.exe` and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. This is the code I am using:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\1\2\3\4\5" | `
        Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | `
        Select-Object @{Name = "Date"; Expression = { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('h:mm tt') }}, `
        @{Name = "Hit"; Expression = { (Get-ChildItem "C:\1\2\3\4\5" -Recurse -Filter "*.png").Count}} | `
        Group-Object Date | Select-Object @{Name = "Time"; Expression = { $_.Name }} , Count, Hit
```

What I get is

```
Time     Count Hit
----     ----- ---
12:00 AM     2   
1:00 AM      2   
2:00 AM      1
```

Any ideas? If you need more clarification, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group-Object` outputs objects with members `Name`, `Count` and `Group` only. To access the properties from the output of the cmdlet piped into `Group-Object` (except the property specified as argument for `Group-Object)`, you need to access the `Group` property, which is an array of all grouped objects. So you need another calculated property for `Hit`.

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\1\2\3\4\5" -Directory |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
    Select-Object @{Name = "Date"; Expression = { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('h:mm tt') }},
                  @{Name = "Hit"; Expression = { ($_ | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter "*.png").Count}} |
    Group-Object Date | 
    Select-Object @{Name = "Time"; Expression = { $_.Name }}, Count, 
                  @{Name = "Hit"; Expression = { ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Hit -sum).sum }}
```

The expression calculates the sum of the `hit` property of all elements of the `Group` array.

Another issue was that you are using the same path for both `Get-ChildItem` calls, so you are actually searching for `*.png` multiple times using the same path. Of course this results in incorrect counts. I've fixed that by specifying `$_` as the path, which is the folder found by the first `Get-ChildItem`.

Also I've added `-Directory` to the top-level `Get-ChildItem` and `-File` to the nested `Get-ChildItem`. Propably won't make a difference in the result, but I think it makes the code clearer. It better expresses the intentions.